# how to use snowball's catalan stemmer?

Tags: python, nltk, snowball

I want to use the catalan stemmer provided in here:
http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/catalan/stemmer.html

However, when I do:

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer   
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("catalan")
```

it says:

> the language Catalan is not supported

could anybody help me? what am I doing wrong?

for Spanish it does work when I type:

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("spanish")
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong.  Supported languages for the SnowballStemmer are found inside the source code, and do not include Catalan:

```
class SnowballStemmer(StemmerI):

    """
    Snowball Stemmer

    The following languages are supported:
    Danish, Dutch, English, Finnish, French, German,
    Hungarian, Italian, Norwegian, Portuguese, Romanian, Russian,
    Spanish and Swedish.
```

Found here: http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/stem/snowball.html

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Then, how you go about calling this catalan stemmer? http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/catalan/stemmer.html'

Comment: woohoo, that is part of a C library.  They have a man page on their site that I suggest you look at: http://snowball.tartarus.org/runtime/use.html